# JSP form doesn't work

Tags: html, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying do do one JSP page to create one object.

This is my jsp page:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Kitsune</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <form:form method="POST" action="/Kitsune/formatador/handleNewCv">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
                        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
                        <input class="btn btn-default" name="save" type="submit" value="Save" />
                        <input class="btn btn-default" name="submitCV" type="submit" value="Submit & Preview" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row " id="accordion">
                    <div class="top-info col-xs-12">
                        <h4>
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#collapseOne" href="#collapseOne">Address & Contact<i class="indicator fa fa-chevron-up pull-right"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="clearfix info-cv">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                         <form role="form">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <form:label path="address">Address</form:label>
                                                <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="address" />
                                            </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                        <form role="form">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <form:label path="postalCode">Postal Code</form:label>
                                                <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="postalCode" />
                                            </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>                                       
                                    </div> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

And my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/handleNewCv", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"save", "!submitCV"})
public String saveCV(CurriculumVitae cv, ModelMap model) {
    logger.info("saving CV");
    model.addAttribute("noteworthy", cv.getNoteworthy());
    model.addAttribute("adress", cv.getAddress());
    return "formatador/dummyf";
}
```

When I submit this form, the Curriculum Vitae in the controller has everything with null but if I remove all the `<form role="form">` then, the CV object has some data. Why this happen?

Comment: where is your form bean declaration in the JSP ? Further why do you have so many forms ?

Comment: You have nested forms, that's not allowed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms Whether it works in some cases is irrelevant because you shouldn't rely on that behavior

Comment: so are you saying that i need to remove all form:stuff from my code ? but then where i place my path to atributtes?